# duplicate application.conf in typesafe config projects

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I am reading some code which uses typesafe config to read the `application.conf` file in the resource folder.  I am using a library which has a `application.conf` in its resource folder and I call this library from another project which has its own `application.conf` in its resources folder.

Will typesafe config be able to read the right config files respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation:

> [The substitution syntax  `${foo.bar}`  will be resolved twice. **First, all the  `reference.conf`  files are merged** and then the result gets resolved. **Second, all the  `application.conf`  are layered over the  `reference.conf`**  and the result of that gets resolved again.](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#note-about-resolving-substitutions-in-referenceconf-and-applicationconf)

So, both libraries will see the same `Config`, which is the result of merging both `application.conf` (assuming both use default behavior and there are no more `application.conf` or `reference.conf` files on the classpath). Each library *should* not just put its configuration in the root, but instead have its own part of config tree: i.e. not

```
debug = true
server = "example.com"
```

but

```
my.cool.library {
  debug = true
  server = "example.com"
}
```

If this rule is followed, the libraries won't conflict. If they use the same path with different meaning, you will have trouble.